# Autocomplete & security - retrieving credentials from local cache?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, autocomplete

Is it possible to retrieve stored credentials from the browser cache if you use auto-complete to fill in a form?

I believe that the data itself is encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible: http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2010/08/breaking-browsers-hacking-auto-complete.html

Comment: +1, I was about to paste a reference to Jeremiah's blog. A couple of additional links from his blog - http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2010/07/i-know-who-your-name-where-you-work-and.html and this one from RSnake's blog - http://ha.ckers.org/weird/safari_autofill.html